# Command not found: composer

Tags: composer-php

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5N6gTVCG_rw&t=9s). When I get to around the 11:48 minute mark, I am supposed to run the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel .
```

To which the terminal response is:

```
zsh: command not found: composer
```

I am not sure if this is necessary, but here is my docker-composer.yml file:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine 
    container_name: nginx
    ports: 
        - "8088:80"
    volumes: 
        - ./src:/var/www/html 
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
        - php
        - mysql
    networks:
        - laravel

mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports: 
        - "4306:3306"
    volumes:
        - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
            MYSQL_USER: homestead
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
        - laravel

php:
    build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php 
    volumes: 
        - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    networks:
        - laravel
```

I had to install homebrew before I could install composer using the commands from the composer website.

The terminal confirmed that Composer version 1.10.10 was successfully installed.

Regardless, I'm still getting "command not found: composer" in the terminal.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you install it locally or globally? If globally, did you add the install directory to your export path?

Comment: I first tried to install it from the VSCode terminal, which was currently in the folder of the site that I'm working on.  Then, I opened up a regular terminal and installed it there, to which I received a successful installation message.

Comment: try to run ```/usr/local/bin/composer``` if you think it installed via Dockerfile..

Comment: @JohnBeasley what `OS` you r using .?

Comment: @KamleshPaul - I am on macOS Catalina version 10.15.6

Comment: Or first run ```which composer``` because sometime when run composer direct it shows command not found but when run ```which composer``` it gives the path and you can run from there.

Comment: @JohnBeasley oh so can u put your docker file code which contain `composer` service

Comment: @MandeepGill `which` will chow `composer` only if it is found within the `PATH`, and obviously it is not there atm

Comment: @KamleshPaul the `composer` command as per his instruction is not ran within the docker container, he needs it locally on his Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem arises when you have composer installed locally.To make it globally executable,run the below command in terminal

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if it doesn't solved the problem with:

```sh
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

After, try:

```sh
sudo -u <user> /usr/local/bin/composer <command> <option>
```

It works for me with nginx's user.